# C Data Structure or Core Foundation?

Tags: macos, data-structures, core-foundation

I am working on an app that works heavily with the file system.

I have a C background and it is a habit to just use C Data Structures as much as possible.

Can anyone comment on how to decide when to use C Data Structures vs the Core Foundation data structures?

OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends a bit on the specific requirements of the application. **If you end up spending too much time implementing the C data structure instead of working on the actual problem, then your best bet is to work with an already existing data structure**.

Also, data structures from a good library are generally well tested and can save you a lot of debugging time.

However if, for example, you are thinking in working on a specific behavior of a red black tree algorithm in order to tackle your problem, then indeed you should better write your own version.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty much common sense: Use Core Foundation when it provides the functionality you need. Use your own data structures when something appropriate has not been provided.